# CloudKit on iOS won't fetch all of my desired records

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

My api for using CloudKit to fetch records for my app, isn't working right anymore. It only started doing this a week or two ago. It fetches fine from the public database, just not the private one.

For example, I have a record type called "Part" that contains some values, including a "datestamp" field. The first time the app is launched, it's supposed to fetch all of the records for Part (and others) in the private database with CKQueryOperation, and then on subsequent launches, it fetches any new ones with CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation. In my personal iCloud account, I have over 1,000 of these records. But the query operation and the fetch changes operation are only able to fetch the exact same ***107*** records and no more. This isn't an issue with the resultLimits and I've implemented checking for a CKQueryCursor. As an experiment, I gave it a predicate to only fetch records with a datestamp of Jan 2018 or later - it returned **0** records. There's another record type that has 12 records in my database, but only **1** is syncing.

I designed my syncing class to be a cross platform API. It works on my iOS, macOS and tvOS targets. ***The macOS target syncs just fine***, even though it's using the exact same code line for line. And the iOS and tvOS has worked fine for almost 2 years. Aside from now using the class inside an NSOperation subclass, almost nothing has changed. I've tried on multiple iPhones, iPads, iOS Simulator instances, iOS versions, Xcode versions. I've tried a different iCloud account. I don't know what the problem is. But this bug is holding me up from releasing a much needed update. I thought maybe it's just a bug on Apple's side in the development environment and will work fine on the public release, but I'm a afraid of disabling all of my users.

```
 protocol CloudData {
    var privateDatabase : CKDatabase { get }
 }

 extension CloudData {
    var privateDatabase : CKDatabase {
       return CKContainer (identifier: "iCloud...").privateDatabase
    }
 }

 final class CloudSync : CloudData {

    func initialSync {

         ...

         // Create an operation to fetch all PARTS
        let partQuery = CKQuery (recordType: "Part", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        let partOperation = CKQueryOperation (query: partQuery)
        partOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { partRecords += [$0] }
        partOperation.zoneID = zoneID
        partOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in

            if let cursorObj = cursor {

                print("Initial Sync - Cursor Found Parts")

                let newOp = CKQueryOperation (cursor: cursorObj)
                newOp.recordFetchedBlock = partOperation.recordFetchedBlock
                newOp.queryCompletionBlock = partOperation.queryCompletionBlock
                self.privateDatabase.add(newOp)

                return
            }
            self.progress.completedUnitCount += 1
            print ("Initial Sync - Part Objects Fetched")


        }

        partOperation.database = privateDatabase

        ...
    }

 }
```

Comment: (1) Show the line defining privateDatabase.  (2) What do you mean by the following?  "For example, I have a record called "Part" that contains some values, including a "datestamp" field. The first time the app is launched, it's supposed to fetch all of the records for Part (and others) in the private database with CKQueryOperation, and then on subsequent launches, it fetches any new ones with CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation."  Part is a record?  And trying to fetch all of the records for Part (record)?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: My apologies on number 2. I miss typed my description. "Part" is a Record TYPE. In Core Data terms it would be an "Entity". So for instance, a user would create a "Part" CKRecord with data like { datestamp = Mar 2018, name = Dan's Part, description = part for Dan}. So the first time the app launches, it fetches all records of that TYPE. Then afterwards, it fetches only the new ones added - like if they have second device that adds a record, then the first device will use CKFetchRecordZoneChanges to get the new records the second device created.

Comment: The "privateDatabase" is just a property defined in a protocol and implemented in a protocol extension. Like this - var privateDatabase  : CKDatabase { return CKContainer (identifier: "iCloud....").privateDatabase } . The CloudSync class conforms to the protocol. I just omitted all the protocol conformances from the class definition in the above example, for brevity.

Comment: If you suggest that you cannot fetch data just for the private database, then you probably need to work on security roles.

Comment: I thought about that. I’m going to look more on that. But the fact is that I CAN fetch from the private database it’s just that it only fetches a limited number of my records. It never gives an error, just returns a small fraction of the records I’m querying for - that I know are there. And each of the records was created by me. Added to that is that the same database, using the same API, querying for the same records, using the same iCloud account, works every single time with the macOS version of my app. If fetches all 1,200 something records. I may have to use one of my TSIs with Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue and it's not a CloudKit bug. It's actually something kind of dumb on my part. In my iCloud entitlements file, I had a line that explicitly set the iCloud session to the "Production" environment instead of the "Development" one. I don't know why I had that there; I must have been debugging something in the production public store and just forgot to undo it when I was done.

Regardless though, I think it should still have worked just fine. It may not have fetched ALL of my private records since most of them are in the development environment, but I had a few that I saved to the production environment too, when I was doing the debugging. Also, I don't understand why the iOS Simulator couldn't get records from EITHER of the databases when it was going through the production environment.

But as long as it's working now, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely CloudKit bug and filing a bug report might be the best option. The CloudKit is not prefect yet.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have problems with large fetches (more than 2 cursors) if I don't assign the query operation to the main operation, in the cursor block.

Try adding `partOperation = newOp` immediately above `self.privateDatabase.add(newOp)`

I don't believe you need that `return` at the end of the cursor block. None of my calls have one.

See if that helps.

Comment: I know that there is usually a problem recursing the way I did in the above code (for the cursor operation). I abbreviated the above code to make it easier to read. In the full class, the query/cursor operations are initialized and returned from a function; this avoids the issue of only being able to run the query twice like you described. I know the return isn't necessary; it's just something I do for my own benefit when I have a lot of code; to make it clear to myself that the execution will end there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I found the source of the issue though. See my own answer below.